# How would I use PDF decimal data to create a download in node react app using md-to-pdf?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, download, blob, pdf-generation

I have data that is being sent from the server to the frontend:

```
"data": {
        "filename": "",
        "content": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                37,
                80,
                68,
                70,
                45,
                49,
                46,
                52,
                10,
                37,
                ...,
```

This is the object I create in the backend using the [md-to-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-to-pdf) library. Since I do not want any temporary space I do not set a destination on the md-to-pdf function, instead I just save the pdf object into a variable and send it back to the frontend and I get what you can see above.

To create the pdf object I just pass in a string which contains a lot of markdown data through the content parameter. This works perfectly when I set a destination, I am able to create a pdf file with the markdown, but when I send the data of the pdf to the frontend..

I believe what I get is the decimal representation of a pdf file. What I am unsure of is how I can use this data on the frontend to create a Blob or something similar?

I have tried sending the data.content to a blob but all I get is a "failed to load the document" error. This is my blob which other than not specifying type, I believe is right.

```
startDownload = (pdf) => {
        const element = document.createElement("a");
        const blob = new Blob([pdf]);
        element.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        element.download = "userTable.pdf";
        element.click();
    };
```

One thing I would like to point out is that if I change the `element.download = "userTable.pdf"` to `element.download = "userTable.md"` and open that on a browser I do not get error but the only thing I am able to see is the text [object object] and a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer but I ended up just sending the json object with the data to the frontend and using a pdf creator library on the frontend.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).